# Titanium iPhone app crash - assertion failed

Tags: ios, crash, titanium-alloy

I am developing an iPhone app using Titanium Alloy. But my app is crashing at random with the error message :

```
assertion failed: 12F70: libxpc.dylib + 71768 [B870B51D-AA85-3686-A7D9-ACD48C5FE153]: 0x7d
```

I am not being able to understand the error.
Please if some one can explain to me what the error means then I work towards fixing the issue.

Other details :

Operating System Mac OS X 10.10 64bit

Titanium CLI Version = 4.0.0-beta3

Titanium SDK Version = 3.5.1.GA

Target Platform = iphone

Thanks,
Bably

Comment: This is might be because  you are using beta CLI, Try with some final version of Titanium CLI.